# Запись образа на флэшку

Tags: ubuntu, iso-образ

Есть *ISO-образ* *Windows 10*, *Ubuntu 14.04* и флешка на 8Gb. Как записать загрузочную флешку для установки?

То есть нужна рабочая  и простая утилита, где нужно указать ссылку на образ и куда записать, и не более..) Поиск ничего рабочего не дал.

Comment: вам на askUbuntu лучше

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 4):

**предуведомление** о загрузке образов **именно** *ms/windows* с *usb-устройств*. подготовка такого носителя —- это нетривиальный процесс и «уложить» его в рамки одной программы/скрипта — длительная (и неблагодарная) работа, которую, как вы, вероятно, уже обнаружили, до сих пор никто не проделал. см. ниже обновление.

---

## копирование образов как таковых

копирование образов в операционной системе *gnu/linux* осуществляется так же, как и копирование любых других файлов — программой `cp`.

в случае с доступом к физическим устройством эта программа, естественно, должна выполняться с *root-овыми* привилегиями. например, используя `sudo`:

```
$ sudo cp /путь/к/файлу/с/образом /dev/блочное-устройство
```

и обратная процедура (с блочного устройства в файл):

```
$ sudo cp /dev/блочное-устройство /путь/к/файлу/с/образом
```

все разделы на *блочном устройстве*, во избежание проблем, должны быть отмонтированы (то, что в графическом интерфейсе для «флэшек» называется как-нибудь вроде «извлечь устройство», применять в данном случае нельзя — usb-устройство будет логически выключено). посмотреть список примонтированных разделов (и уточнить, куда именно они примонтированы) можно программами `df` или `mount`, отмонтировать:

```
$ sudo umount /путь/к/разделу/блочного/устройства
```

или

```
$ sudo umount /путь/к/точке/монтирования
```

определить имя нужного *блочного устройства* можно по-разному. в случае извлекаемого *usb-накопителя* это проще делать, просмотрев последние записи кольцевого буфера ядра (сразу после подключения устройства) с помощью программы `dmesg`. примерный вывод:

```
$ dmesg | tail
...
[17614.102720] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

`sdb` — в данном случае и есть имя *блочного устройства*

вот это имя и надо подставить в команду:

```
$ sudo cp /путь/к/файлу/с/образом /dev/sdb
```

учтите, что сразу же после завершения этой команды ещё не вся буферизованная информация «сброшена» на устройство. для очистки буферов выполните программу:

```
$ sync
```

после этого *usb-устройство* можно извлекать.

## обновление по поводу установочных образов ms/windows

проблема здесь заключается не в том, «как бы так хитро записать образ», а в том, что *стандартная* программа установки *ms/windows*, после запуска, в поиске остальных файлов, необходимых для продолжения установки, будет просматривать лишь носители, отвечающие следующим требованиям:

это либо cd/dvd-устройство, либо устройство, подключенное через интерфейс [sata/pata](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SATA) **и** не являющееся *съёмным*.

т.н. «usb-флэшки» подключаются через интерфейс *sata*, как и традиционные современные «винчестеры», но, в отличие от «винчестеров», рапортуют о том, что они являются *съёмными*.

посмотреть результат такого рапорта в операционной системе *gnu/linux* можно в файле `/sys/block/имя-устройства/removable`. например, так сообщает о себе «usb-флэшка» с именем *sdf*:

```
$ cat /sys/block/sdf/removable
1
```

а вот так сообщает о себе «винчестер» (sda):

```
$ cat /sys/block/sda/removable
0
```

кстати, этот рапорт ничуть не изменится, если «винчестер» подключить не напрямую к sata-контроллеру на материнской плате, а, например, к контроллеру usb через «переходник» usb-sata/pata.

для «обхода» подобной логики программы-инсталлятора, как я понимаю, существует три пути (отсортированы по степени реалистичности):

1. записать образ на cd/dvd или на «винчестер»
2. изменить микро-программу внутри «usb-флэшки» так, чтобы она рапортовала о своей «несъёмности» ([для некоторых устройств это возможно, но нет никаких гарантий, что устройство при этом не превратится в «кирпич»](https://superuser.com/q/391176/454489))
3. «пропатчить» программу-инсталлятор так, чтобы она искала необходимые файлы **и** на съёмных sata/pata-носителях

Answer (score 3):

Воспользуйтесь утилитой **dd**

```
dd if=ОБРАЗ_ДИСКА.iso of=/dev/ДИСК
```

Comment: скажите, пожалуйста, а почему `dd`, а не `cp`? просто для разнообразия?

Comment: cp копирует, а dd разворачивает образ.

Comment: простите мне мою (возможную) глупость, но что означает «разворачивает образ»?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cp
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd

Comment: спасибо огромное за ссылки. жаль, что там нет ничего, что бы мне не было известно уже как минимум лет десять. особенно жаль, что по второй ссылке нет разъяснения, что вы подразумевали под словами «разворачивать образ». придётся мне с этим смириться.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: лично я использую dd вместо cp при работе с `/dev/sdX` (когда GUI по каким-то обстоятельствам не использую), чтобы напомнить себе, что я собираюсь выполнить опасную операцию. Помогает также что `dd` имеет необычные для GNU утилит опции (что также обостряет внимание). Концептуально `cp` я воспринимаю на более высоком уровне абстракции (знает об атрибутах файлов, работает с директориями), а [`dd` как простую обёртку read,write, seek системных вызовов](https://www.vidarholen.net/contents/blog/?p=479)

Answer (score 1):

Тебе нужна утилита UNetbootin. Она очень проста в использовании. Скармливаешь ей образ и делаешь запись. Предварительно можно отформатировать.

Answer (score 0):

С Windows 7 прокатывал такой вариант:

1. Ставим gparted.
2. Форматируем через него флэшку в NTFS.
3. Не забываем установить на флэшку флаг "boot" через управление флагами во всё том же gparted.
4. Монтируем образ с windows.
5. Просто копируем содержимое на флэшку через `cp -r` или `rsync -avrh` или drag'n'drop.

Comment: На современных компах с UEFI можно просто скопировать распакованный образ Win 8, 8.1 или 10 на флешку с FAT32 и грузится с неё без всяких плясок.

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйся программой Unetbootin https://unetbootin.github.io/

Никогда не подводила [image: введите сюда описание изображения]