# Загрузочная флэшка из под Linux Kali 2.0

Tags: linux

Как сделать загрузочную флэшку с UBUNTU из под Linux Kali 2.0 ?

Comment: unetbootin, если не смогли нагуглить.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов я нагуглил, не получается установить...

Comment: Ваш вопрос звучит "как сделать", а не "как установить". sudo apt-get install unetbootin короче.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов не удалось найти пакет

Comment: берёте образ и копируете программой `cp`. подробнее: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/435073/178576

Answer (score 5, accepted):

копия [ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/435073/178576) к немного другому вопросу.

---

## копирование образов как таковых

копирование образов в операционной системе *gnu/linux* осуществляется так же, как и копирование любых других файлов — программой `cp`.

в случае с доступом к физическим устройством эта программа, естественно, должна выполняться с *root-овыми* привилегиями. например, используя `sudo`:

```
$ sudo cp /путь/к/файлу/с/образом /dev/блочное-устройство
```

и обратная процедура (с блочного устройства в файл):

```
$ sudo cp /dev/блочное-устройство /путь/к/файлу/с/образом
```

все разделы на *блочном устройстве*, во избежание проблем, должны быть отмонтированы (в графическом интерфейсе для «флэшек» это называется как-нибудь вроде «извлечь устройство»).

определить имя нужного *блочного устройства* можно по-разному. в случае извлекаемого *usb-накопителя* это проще делать, просмотрев последние записи кольцевого буфера ядра (сразу после подключения устройства) с помощью программы `dmesg`. примерный вывод:

```
$ dmesg | tail
...
[17614.102720] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

`sdb` — в данном случае и есть имя *блочного устройства*

вот это имя и надо подставить в команду:

```
$ sudo cp /путь/к/файлу/с/образом /dev/sdb
```

учтите, что сразу же после завершения этой команды ещё не вся буферизованная информация «сброшена» на устройство. для очистки буферов выполните программу:

```
$ sync
```

после этого *usb-устройство* можно извлекать.

Comment: С первого абзаца узнаю ваш стиль изложения. :)

Comment: @NickVolynkin, угу, мои «рыжие кудри» уже примелькались. пора применять контрабандный товар с малой арнаутской.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin вобщем я тупо скопировал образ на флэшку и всё пошло :) спасибо :)

Comment: @maximadelevich, так и должно было быть. «загрузочный образ» — это, упрощённо говоря, и есть содержимое блочного устройства.