# Не могу запустить Linux на OrangePI plus 2E

Tags: linux, debian, orange-pi

Мною было опробовано 4 дистрибутивов(Armbian,Ubuntu{LXTE/MATE},Debian) и все валились c одним и тем же логом в конце.

И да вполне штатно запускается Android(который был пред установлен с завода). Правда он толком не работает, браузер и PlayMarket не запускаются но работают программы для тестирование ,а также wifi адаптер(всё корректно подключается).
В чём проблема и как её решить?

[Видео запуска системы](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3ByHq4h0Q9Q&spfreload=10)

Возможно мною было нарушена технология установки на SD карту, опишу её ниже.

1.Вставил и отформатировал sd карту c помощью gparted (после каждой переустановки приходилось менять таблицу разделов на dos)

2.Далее разархивировал образы дистрибутивов.

3.Запись c помощью Etcher.

4.(После записи появлялось окно что завершено успешно, но возможно данные повреждены на устройстве.)

(Все манипуляции проводились в Ubuntu 15.10)

[image: Причина падения ?!]

Comment: пункты 1, 3, 4 не нужны. надо просто скопировать образ на устройство. [абсолютно типовое действие](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/435073/178576)

Comment: Неочевидно из вопроса, фото крэша — это то самое одинаковое сообщение из-за которого вы считаете ничего не работает?

Comment: Да вы правы поменял несколько дистрибутивов.
Падают все при загрузки не измененным остаётся только этот лог.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. ...
> 2. ...
> 3. ...
> 4. ...

очень уж сложную процедуру вы придумали.

всё, что вам нужно — это записать файл с образом [**непосредственно** на блочное устройство](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/435073/178576):

```
$ sudo cp файл /dev/устройство
```

---

для проверки скачал файл `Raspbian_For_OrangePi_plus2e.img.xz` с сайта [piboard.io](http://piboard.io/topic/6/%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-orange-pi). файл сжатый (размер 904777684 байт):

```
$ file Raspbian_For_OrangePi_plus2e.img.xz
Raspbian_For_OrangePi_plus2e.img.xz: XZ compressed data
```

естественно, надо его разжать:

```
$ xz -d Raspbian_For_OrangePi_plus2e.img.xz
```

получился файл `Raspbian_For_OrangePi_plus2e.img` (размер 3984588800 байт). это образ блочного устройства:

```
$ file Raspbian_For_OrangePi_plus2e.img
Raspbian_For_OrangePi_plus2e.img: DOS/MBR boot sector;
partition 1 : ID=0x83, start-CHS (0x2,170,41), end-CHS (0x8,54,60), startsector 40960, 83968 sectors;
partition 2 : ID=0x83, start-CHS (0x8,54,61), end-CHS (0x1d8,5,58), startsector 124928, 7045120 sectors
```

вот его и надо записывать непосредственно на блочное устройство. подробно процедура определения имени устройства [описана в уже упомянутом выше ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/435073/178576) на аналогичный (по смыслу) вопрос.