# Как понять какие драйверы требуются дистрибутиву Windows 7 x64?

Tags: windows, драйвер, live-usb, usb3.0

Я пытаюсь установить Windows 7 с флешки. На этапе начала установки вылезает ошибка "не найдены драйвера оптического привода", хотя установщик сам до этого смог загрузиться с флешки. Разные варианты решения не помогли, хочу найти именно драйвера да закрыть эту проблему. 
Но вопрос, какие драйвера искать на самом деле и для чего? Для флешки этой конкретной (пробовал разные), для USB 3.0 (хотя ставлю в слот 2.0)? Каких драйверов на самом деле не хватает в таком случае дистрибутиву винды?

Comment: Другой дистрибутив не пробовали? Я бы поставил 8-ку, она сама подтащит все нужные драйвера и проблема будет решена.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду она через инет их подтянет? Другой дистрибутив не пробовал пока, думал везде одно и то же.

Comment: Да, если не найдет из стандартных в комплекте, то без проблем подтянет из инета. Сталкивался с чем-то подобным при установке 7-ки на достаточно древний ноутбук, с 8-кой все норм прошло, впрочем как и с 10-кой.    Вы можете сначала попробовать другой дистрибутив, чтобы отсечь этот момент, а потом в крайнем случае попробовать поставить 8/10-ку.

Comment: посмотрите [этот мой ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/435073/178576), начиная с той части, где про установочные образы ms/winidows.

Comment: Не панацея на счёт слота. Щас 2-й и 3-й усб лежат внутри одного чипа и без дров на этот чип ничего работать не будет. Я решил для себя проблему просто раскатывая образ по сети и собрав образ под свои нужды. Но для разовой операции - это явный оверхэд.

Comment: Да, если на матери есть слоты PS/2 - они 100% работают. Воткни клаву через переходник или одолжи у кого-нибудь.