# Загрузка компонентов программы установки с компакт диска

Tags: linux, установка

Ставлю Kali Linux с флэшки на HP Pavilion. Сначала была проблема на этапе "Поиск и монтирование CD-ROM". Решил её командами

```
umount mnt
mount /dev/sdb1 /cdrom
```

Теперь ошибка на этапе "Загрузка компонентов программы установки с компакт-диска":

> Невозможно считать данные с компакт-диска. Убедитесь, что диск вставлен в привод CD-ROM. Если дальнейшие попытки ни к чему не приведут, вам следует проверить целостность данных на компакт-диске. Не удаётся скопировать файл с компакт-диска.

Проверка целостности компакт-диска проходит успешно. Пишет, что компакт-диск исправен

Comment: надеюсь, вы копировали [образ файловой системы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/435073/178576), а не файлы.

Comment: @alexander barakin, тоесть если я хочу именно установить, то мне нужно просто iso образ на флэшку закинуть?

Comment: да, надо копировать **образ всей файловой системы**. на какой носитель — несущественно в данном случае: как и большинство современных загрузочных образов, образ kali умеет стартовать и находить сам себя при записи на любое популярное блочное устройство — компакт-диск, hdd-носитель, usb-носитель.

Comment: @alexander barakin, то есть я целый месяц страдал фигней, записывая образ Руфусом? Тогда в каком случае Руфус нужен?

Comment: понятие не имею, что такое «руфус», и чем он(а) занимается.

Comment: @alexander barakin, даже установка не запустилась. No bootable device -- insert boot disk and press any key

Comment: попробую сыграть в телепата. возможно, вы записали образ не на блочное устройство (например, `/dev/sdb`), а на первый раздел блочного устройства (`/dev/sdb1`). ну и bios (uefi) компьютера должен распознать ваш usb-носитель как загрузочное устройство.

Comment: @Flippy извените за не скромный вопрос, а вы не читали с офф сайта гайд по созданию флешек и  DVD https://docs.kali.org/downloading/kali-linux-live-usb-install

Comment: @Hellseher, мне не лайв нужна а независимая система прямо на диске рядом с виндовс