# Запись образа Windows 10 на USB носитель

Tags: linux, usb, iso-образ

Столкнулся с проблемой записи Windows на флешку в Debian 9. Etcher (далее и dd) ничем помочь не могут, BIOS флешку видит, а бутаться, говорит, не на чем. Собственно планирую установить на внешний HDD для работы.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/435073/178576

Comment: https://onetransistor.blogspot.ru/2015/09/uefi-ntfs-bootable-windows-usb-linux.html

Comment: Лучшая программа которую я знаю, Rufus... Вот оф. сайт  http://rufus.akeo.ie/?locale=ru

Comment: @Air У меня Linux .-.

Comment: Ну да его  вроде для Linux  нет...

Comment: Я ставил виртуалку, туда образ 10, изнутри уже записывал образ на флешку с помощью ultraIso