# Linux / Unable to find a medium containing a live file system

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, deepin, manjaro

Устройство: Acer Aspire-V3 571G.
Предыдущая ОС(на одном винте SSD 128):
1) Windows(40GB)
2) Linux(45GB/30GB/12GB)

Понадобилось переустановить обе ОС. Установил Windows с USB(3.0), начал устанавливать Linux(Deepin, Manjaro, Ubuntu) появляется ошибка.

```
Unable to find a medium containing a live file system.
```

Устанавливались все ОС с этого USB через UltraISO. Образы оригинальные. Разделы форматировались и делились. Пробовал другое USB-устройство, перекачивал образы. На виртуальном машине образы работают без проблем.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Очень странно. Всегда использовал UltraISO(Windows, Linux) записывал без проблем. Записал образ через **Rufus** и Linux установился как надо.

Answer (score 1):

Варианты решения:

- Переключить в BIOS в разделе SATA с IDE на AHCI
- Попробовать другой порт USB
- Переключить USB3 в режим USB2 (BIOS)
- Переключить UEFI в Legacy (BIOS)
- Включить Контроллер IOMMU (некоторые материнки BIOS)

Comment: и самое главное — [записать образ так, как и задумано, непосредственно на блочное устройство, без каких-либо модификаций, без использования каких-либо вспомогательных дополнительных программ. ведь всё необходимое — программа *cp* — есть непосредсвтенно в составе любого дистрибутива операционной системы *gnu/linux*](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/435073/178576).

Comment: К сожалению, ни один из вариантов не помог.

Comment: Как вы записываете образ Linux?