# Как запустить Lenovo T440P с флешки?

Tags: debian, boot, bios

Записывал три раза на флешку Debian 9 с помощью Unetbootin, dd и cp.

Запускаю ноутбук с нажатой F12, выбираю USB, появляется черный экран на секунду потом опять окно с выбором устройств. С hdd запускается нормально.

Что может быть не так? Флешка рабочая, с помощью нее ставил Debian 9, который сейчас на ноутбуке.

Флешка отформатирована в FAT32.

Comment: А зачем вам запускать Debian с флешки, раз у вас уже есть система на hdd? Или у вас не стоит Debain на hdd?

Comment: Я переустановить хочу систему. Запустить установщик с флешки, очистить диск и поставить с нуля.

Comment: У вас только с Debian такая проблема или с другими системами тоже? Попробуйте через rufus записать образ.

Comment: Уже нет возможности тестировать. Но именно с этой флешки уже установил деб, который сейчас стоит. Опят же, хочу заметить, что вопрос в том, почему при нажатии на USB не пишет ошибку и не появляется экран (хотя бы с мигающей строкой), а просто возвращает назад на страницу выбора устройства. Вижу подобное впервые.

Comment: У меня есть предположение, что у вашего bios проблемы с порядком загрузки, хотя влиять не должно, но кто знает. Попробуйте, поменять порядок загрузки, выбрав флешку в разделе "Boot".

Comment: У меня есть ноутбук t440p на котором сейчас стоит debian. Этот debian я установил с флешки. Сейчас я хочу переустановить на этом ноутбуке с той же самой флешки систему. Но при выборе в меню этой флешки ничего не происходит.

Comment: Я вручную выбираю устройство через Startup device menu (f12)

Comment: Вы читали мой вопрос? Написал же, что использовал разные методы. Если бы я неправильно настроил, то показывалось бы сообщение, что это не bootable устройство.

Comment: Тогда мой совет таков, пропишите liveCD вручную через Grub, после сохраните настройки Grub, а затем запустите уже при старте с HDD саму флешку. Я, надеюсь, вы в курсе, что такое Grub?

Comment: Только что ставил рут на флешку, меня выбрасывает в окно выбора устройства. Ввел set root=(hd1) chain.. и в конце boot. Открылось то окно, которое появляется при нажатии f12

Comment: В таком случае, я к сожалению, не знаю в чём проблема, и не смогу помочь. Надеюсь другие участники вам помогут.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Запись образа на флэшку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/435068/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%84%d0%bb%d1%8d%d1%88%d0%ba%d1%83)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему.

До этого указывал цифру в пути, примерно так:

dd if=путь.iso of=/dev/**sdb1**

Нужно было указывать примерно так:

dd if=путь.iso of=/dev/**sdb**