# BIOS не реагирует на загрузочную флешку

Tags: linux, bios

Помогите пожалуйста.

BIOS не реагирует на загрузочную флешку.
Саму флешку при запуске boot menu (у меня клавиша F8) видит, но когда я выбираю ее для загрузки, то комп просто игнорирует ее и загружает установленную ОС.

Прилагаю некоторые данные:

- OS: Linux Mint 18.3
- Материнская плата: M5A78L -M LX3
- Версия биоса: 1201
- Флешка точно исправна и загрузочная
- дисковода нет
- в самом биосе разбираюсь плохо

Проблема скорее всего не в ОС а в биосе, так как до Linux стояла Windows 10 и проблема била точно такая же.

Заранее СПАСИБО.

Comment: Это уже било давно, поэтому точно не уверен, но на Windows 7 таких проблем не било.

Comment: А всё-таки проверьте эту флэшку на другом компе - там загрузка пойдёт?

Comment: А как вы записывали образ на флешку?

Comment: Решил проверить на другом компе. Он отказался открывать флешку, зразу предлагал форматирование, но на линуксе у меня на компе открывалась нормально. Записывал образ через стандартний на линуксе "Запись образа на USB-накопитель". Если это неправильно, то скажите как на линуксе ето лучше сделать.

Comment: *Флешка точно исправна и загрузочная* Флешка - Legacy или UEFI? И укажите модель материнки, на которой с неё удачно грузитесь, а также режим загрузки. *Саму флешку при запуске boot menu (у меня клавиша F8) видит* В бут-меню - одна запись для флешки или две?

Comment: Флешка точно исправна и загрузочная Флешка - Legacy или UEFI?
Скажите пожалуйста как это проверить.

Comment: Проверил на другом ноутбуке, у которого есть поддержка UEFI (у меня ее нет), поставил и на UEFI и на Legacy флешку на первое место. Но без толку, через биос флешка не грузится. Когда нажимаешь на setup то загрузка начинается. Походу флешка не является загрузочной. Но как на Linux сделать ее загрузочной? Я пробовал делать образ через стандартный  "Запись образа на USB-накопитель" а также через программу "UNetbootin". Но ничего не получилось. Да знаю кривые мои руки, но все же скажите как сделать ее загрузочной.

Comment: *как сделать ее загрузочной* — в вашем случае — никак. того, что образ, который вы записываете, загрузочный — уже достаточно. трудности обычно возникают с записью: пользователи, начитавшись интернетов (и опираясь на свой windows-опыт, где это действительно проблематично), пытаются использовать какие-то абсолютно излишние «унетбутины», «записи образов...» и т.п. ненужности. [программы *cp* — более чем достаточно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/435073/178576)

Comment: У нас в конторе попалась серия флешек, которые на половине компьютеров просто не видятся. Попробуйте банально флешку другого производителя.

Comment: *как сделать ее загрузочной* - Загрузочным должно быть не устройство (флэшка) а раздел на этом устройстве. Для того, что бы сделать раздел загрузочным надо: 1) Отмонтировать флэшку (umount) 2) Запустить *fdisk* в режиме рута 3) Выдать команду 'a' на желаемый раздел. Но, подозреваю, что флаг загрузки там и так уже стоит.. Дело не в этом. Я то же как-то раз пользовался "UNetbootin" и у меня тоже ни фига не получилось.

Comment: * программы cp — более чем достаточно* - э... А что - команда CP копирует и таблицу разделов?! И SPL она же копирует ?!! И дерево устройств ?!!!

Comment: Решил даную проблему пошаговой инструкцией по етой ссилке(мне помог вариант №1):[losst](https://losst.ru/zagruzochnaya-fleshka-windows-v-linux)

Answer (score -1):

Современные биосы обычно настроены на 8 или 10 windows. Если они изначально стояли.

В биосе стоит защита на невозможность загрузиться с флешки в меню secure. Далее необходимо перезагрузиться. и в настройках usb переключить один пункт. В общем пошагово не расскажу, т.к. есть отличия в биосе. Но теперь забив в youtube запрос сразу находиться ответ.

Это видио для смены hdd на MBR (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fPqQp-TNpNE&feature=youtu.be). А по поводу загрузки лучше искать по названию компании и модели.

У меня на ASUS  пришлось ставить пункт запуска драйвера в bios, а потом этот драйвер находил все флешки.В общем с каждой моделью свои танцы с бубном

Comment: *Современные биосы обычно настроены на 8 или 10 windows.* отнести указанную материнку к современной невозможно даже с перепою...