# Не получается установить Windows 10 через флеш-загрузчик (ОС Linux)

Tags: linux, windows, flash, boot, uefi

добрые люди!
Мне срочно необходима ваша помощь!

Сейчас я нахожусь на ОС Manjaro Linux и мне необходимо установить на основу Windows 10 (не спрашивайте почему).
Как бы не пытался, флешка просто меня убивает. Использую ISO образ винды внутри флешки-загрузчика (записав через dd и не только). Но в момент появления должгоданных точечек по кругу и выбора русского языка в установщике, мне прилетает уважаемый привет от какого-то дравейра (во вложениях скрин).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дальше конец! Не знаю что и делать! Он не может определить диски, которые размечены для Linux? What?

Нужна помощь, как можно скорее!

Comment: Что значит "установить на основу Windows 10"? Сделать дуалбут или затереть предыдущую систему?

Comment: @dIm0n избавиться от Linux и поставить Windows 10 на SSD как наш любимый Disk C

Comment: @dIm0n выручи дружище!

Comment: Пробовали способы [отсюда](https://remontka.pro/required-driver-missing-windows-install/)?

Comment: @dIm0n да, пробовал

Comment: @dIm0n единственное, через rufus нет, потому что с wine он не видит почему-то моих флешек и там нечего выбирать было

Comment: Возможно, проблема именно с флешкой. Если есть другие или дисковод, то попробуйте с них http://forum.oszone.net/thread-338124.html

Comment: сейчас попробую

Comment: нет, проблема не с флешкой!

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/453716/191416