# Как клонировать Linux с одной флешки на другую? Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

Использую Raspberry Pi. Есть две флешки изначально с одинаковыми системами. Одну систему сломал до kernel panic (флешки целые и рабочие, структура осталась, не поставил точку перед rm и всё удалилось не из текущего каталога, а из корневого).

Есть ли софт, с помощью которого можно полностью клонировать систему с рабочей флешки на сломанную? Для Windows я вроде видел такой софт в действии, не вспомню сейчас название. Флешки сделаны через Raspberry Pi Imager для Raspberry Pi, поэтому открыть через проводник и скопировать нельзя.

Гуглил, попробовал напрямую скопировать через `cp`, столкнулся с рядом проблем, которые связаны с тем что флешка для Raspberry Pi имеет сложную структуру разделов и нужно знать что от куда, куда и как копировать.

Если кто-нибудь скинет название софта или пошаговую инструкцию для Raspberry Pi как это можно сделать без софта, то буду благодарен.

Comment: `пробовал напрямую скопировать, сталкивался с рядом проблем` и с какими проблемами вы столкнулись при [выполнении программы cp](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/435073/178576)?

Comment: Я бы не хотел продолжать в этом направлении обсуждение, потому что разбираться в тех проблемах дольше, чем заново записать систему и настроить её. Поэтому интересуют варианты с софтом или готовой инструкцией. Если их нет, то буду записывать заново и настраивать. Я написал о проблемах, чтобы описать ситуацию и рассказать о том, что пробовал и в каком направлении хочу двигаться. За ссылку спасибо, ответ прочитаю и попробую. Если коротко, проблемы связаны со структурой флешки для Raspberry Pi.

Comment: `$ sudo cp /dev/sdx /dev/sdy`. здесь `/dev/sdx` — источник, а `/dev/sdy` — получатель. естественно, получатель должен быть не меньше, чем источник. более подробно — по ссылке выше. прямо пошагово.

Comment: На основе комментариев поправил вопрос. Надеюсь, что станет понятнее. Мне нужно клонировать систему с одной флешки на другую, чтобы она заработала.

Comment: Копирование устройства целиком неизбежно скопирует всю структуру всех разделов. Непонятно в чём проблема у вас, согласно вашему описанию `sudo cp /dev/sdx /dev/sdy` должен замечательно работать

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Я понял, что я не так написал и что мне надо сделать. Я не сказал, что Linux в котором я работал и флешка которую мне надо скопировать это одно и то же. Я так делал, потому что картридер у меня только один, но в принципе я могу поискать ещё один.

Comment: Всё равно ничего не понятно, что означает фраза «это одно и то же» и как это мешает сделать cp?

Comment: У меня две флешки. Linux я запускаю с одной из них и пытаюсь копировать с неё на сломанную флешку. Чтобы скопировать с одной флешки на другую при помощи cp /dev/sdx /dev/sdy мне нужно найти ещё один картридер и запустить копирование на третьем Linux. Потому что при cp  /  /dev/sdy у меня скопировалось только часть системы, потому что, если я правильно понял, у Raspberry Pi три раздела mmbcblk0p1, mmbcblk0p3 и mmbcblk0p3.

Comment: Во-первых, команда `cp / /dev/sdy` является бредом, потому что нельзя записать каталог в файл. Во-вторых, вы пытаетесь скопировать систему, загрузившись с этой самой системы, что ли? Так делать нельзя, потому что в процессе копирования работающая файловая система может внезапно измениться, и в итоге после копирования с большой вероятностью получится убитая файловая система

Comment: снять копию из под работающей системы можно [попробовать так](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Rsync#Full_system_backup): `rsync -aAXHv --exclude={"/dev/*","/proc/*","/sys/*","/tmp/*","/run/*","/mnt/*","/media/*","/lost+found"} / /path/to/backup` , естественно подправить под свои нужды.

Comment: @Zt. а вот это уже точно не воссоздаст сложную структуру разделов

Comment: а зачем ему воссоздавать сложную структуру разделов ? он же просто rm в корень сделал.

Comment: @Zt. а затем, что он уже наверняка убил разделы предыдущими попытками копирования (если вдруг не убил, то везёт)

Comment: Спасибо! Попробую.

Comment: Всем спасибо за помощь, все комментарии помогли мне разобраться и решить проблему. Получилось скопировать систему, загрузившись с этой системы через cp. Моими ошибками были, что я пытался копировать через cp / /dev/sdy и что не посмотрел где располагалась система, а располагалась она не на sdx, а в mmbcblk0. Получается, что мне помогла команда cp /dev/mmbcblk0 /dev/sda

Comment: Нужно ли мне написать ответ, чтобы закрыть вопрос или достаточно отписаться в комментариях?

Comment: @Alexandr, будет отлично, если напишете ответ на свой вопрос!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем спасибо за помощь в комментариях, вы помогли мне разобраться и решить проблему. Получилось скопировать систему загрузившись с этой же самой системы. Мне помогла команда `cp /dev/mmbcblk0 /dev/sda`, где `mmbcblk0` это копируемая система с которой я загрузился, `sda` - флешка.